# Error when get value from input[type="hidden"]

Tags: jquery

in index.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="2" />
```

in script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#button').click(function(){
       var id = $(this).prev('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
       var type = $(this).prev('input[type="hidden"][name="type"]').val();
       alert(id);
       alert(type);

});
```

when I run file index.php, result is undefined, how to fix it

Comment: Well, for one thing, only one object can be directly previous to the button element, so at best you'd only find one of the inputs, and only if the button comes directly after it in the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prev()` only gets the imminently preceding element and at least the "id" element doesn't precede the button.

I'm guessing the button and the inputs share the same parent, so you probably could use:

```
var id = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
var type = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"][name="type"]').val();
```

You'll need to add the surrounding HTML and the HTML of the button if this doesn't work.

EDIT: Another alternative maybe to use `prevAll()` instead of `prev()`.

Answer (score 3):

**Why don't you just select from root?**

```
>var id = $('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();
>var type = $('input[type="hidden"][name="type"]').val();
```

Comment: This may be dangerous if there are multiple similar forms/input elements on the page.

Comment: You can't have two inputs with the same name value

Comment: What's the use? Unless it's an "array-ish" name like name="users[]" ? (I was thinking of the same form, not different forms, sorry if I was being unclear)

Comment: A) There could be multiple forms with the same element names. B) Brackets (`[]`) are not a requirement of HTML when you have multiple inputs with the same name. It's a (bad) requirement of PHP. Other web languages/platforms support "array-ish" inputs without brackets quite fine.

Answer (score 1):

if you use prev() for the element name "id" ,there is no immediate
   previous sibling.

> **var id = $(this).prev('input[type="hidden"][name="id"]').val();**

this cause the error '**undefined**'.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there is no need to use `[type="hidden"]`. Try simplify selector, like this:
`$(this).prev('input[name="id"]').val();`